# how to create a stream providing f(n)=f(n-2)+f(n-3) in scala

Tags: scala, stream

I tried this:

```
val s1:Stream[Int]=1 #:: 0 #:: 1 #:: 1 #:: (s1.tail.tail.tail,s1.tail.tail).zipped.map{(c,d) => c + d}.toStream
```

but

```
s1(5)
```

raises a stackoverflow...

I succeeded in writing the correct definition with 2 parameters :

```
val s2:Stream[Int]=1 #:: 0 #:: 1 #:: 1 #:: (s2.tail.tail.tail.zip(s2.tail.tail)).map{n=> n._1+n._2}
```

but i the future I will want to add more than 2 lists, that's why I would like to be able to use "zipped" instead of "zip".

thanks

Comment: `zipped` is broken for infinite sequences. Don't use it, you could only use it for a 2 or 3 tuple anyway.

Answer (score 1):

What about `Stream.iterate((1, 0, 1))({case (a, b, c) => (b, c, a + b)}).map(_._3)`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this code produces your sequence correctly:

```
val s:Stream[Int]=1 #:: 0 #:: 1 #:: 1 #:: (s.tail zip s.tail.tail).map {t => t._1 + t._2}
```

For example:

```
s(7) = 3
s(8) = 4
s(10) = 7
```